# как достать из массива значения определенный полей?

Tags: php, массивы, laravel

как оставить в массиве только значения xar?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В заголовке у вас "*достать значения*", а  в теле вопроса "*оставить значения*". Разница есть и методы в зависимости от этого - тоже разные. Если "оставить", то вам ниже уже ответил @entithat, а если "достать", то можно так: `array_column($array, 'xar');` . Точное формулирование вопроса, тянет за собой оптимальное решение. P.S. Вместо кода на скриншоте, лучше выкладывать отформатированный код в виде строки. Для массивов, чтобы удобней было с ним экспериментировать - `var_export()`

Comment: спасибо за ответ. array_column($array, 'xar');  подошел

Answer (score 2):

Подробней о [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php)

```
$array = [
    [
        'xar' => 1, 
        'viewBag' => [1, 2]
    ],
    [
        'xar' => 2, 
        'viewBag' => [3, 4]
    ]
];

print_r(
        array_map(function($item) {
            return ['xar' => $item['xar']];
        }, $array)
);
```

Вывод:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [xar] => 1
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [xar] => 2
    )
)
```